# How to write a junit test case for fetching a file and reading it from Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Here is my code :

```
 public String getDate() throws IOException {
    StringBuilder fileURI = new StringBuilder(locationName);
    fileURI.append(fileName);
    S3ObjectInputStream ts = null;
    ts = (S3ObjectInputStream) s3Services.getResourceStream(fileURI.toString());
    String timeStamp;
    String onlyDate = null;
    LocalDate mydate;
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ts))) {
        timeStamp = reader.readLine();
        onlyDate = timeStamp.substring(0, 10);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(onlyDate);
        mydate= date.minusDays(1);
     
    }
    return mydate.toString();
}
```

I am working on junit for the first time.

I need to mock s3Services and test that getResourceStream() is called with the expected value.

I am trying to mock out S3ObjectInputStream and make sure the correct methods on it are called.

```
 @Test
public void testgetDate() throws IOException {
Mockito.mock(Service.class);
StringBuilder fileURI = new StringBuilder("test");
fileURI.append("testFile.txt");
Mockito.mock(S3ObjectInputStream .class);
S3ObjectInputStream ts = null;
Mockito.when(s3Services.getResourceStream(fileURI.toString())).thenReturn(ts);
service.getDate();
```

}

Comment: what error are you getting? As I can see there are many error in your code like initialize timestamp and you should create injectmocks of Service class. anf thenReturn method should have some value. did you get that all point?

Comment: I have created injectMocks and initialized timestamp.. I am not getting any errors, but I am not getting any coverage except the first 2 lines

Comment: Hi Varsha, you update your code please as I said lots of known field is there like "s3Services?" and many more.